# Как вывести div с id классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

скрипт который выводит `<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>` после удачной операции, как вывести его именно в `<div id="block">`
я предпологаю что типа такого должно быть

```
$('#block'). this_desc.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
```

но не совсем понимаю.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.this_desc').blur(function(){
        this_desc = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:'action=updateDescr&description_val=' + this_desc.val() + '&page_id=' + this_desc.attr('data-id'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                this_desc.attr('readonly','readonly').next().html('Сохраняю...');
            },
            success:function(results){
                this_desc.removeAttr('readonly').next().html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>');
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос то? Почему не подходит
$('#block').html('<span style="color:#0FB10F">Сохранено</span>'); ?

Comment: @Ofer потому что нужно сразу что бы срабатывала функция this_desc.removeAttr('readonly')